# SmartGwt ListGrid.setAlwaysShowEditors(true) issue

Tags: java, smartgwt, smartclient

We have basic ListGrid where one of the fields is editable and editor for this field always should be displayed, here is creation code

```
ListGrid listPanel = new ListGrid();
listPanel.setDataFetchMode(FetchMode.PAGED);
listPanel.setDataSource(datasource);
listPanel.setAutoFetchData(true);
listPanel.setAlwaysShowEditors(true);
listPanel.setCanEdit(true);
listPanel.setAutoSaveEdits(false);
listPanel.setSaveByCell(false);
listPanel.setEditOnFocus(true);
listPanel.setEditEvent(ListGridEditEvent.CLICK);
```

editable field is created here

```
ListGridField manualScoreColumn = new ListGridField("score", "Score");
manualScoreColumn.setType(ListGridFieldType.INTEGER);
manualScoreColumn.setCanEdit(true);
manualScoreColumn.setValidateOnChange(true);
manualScoreColumn.setValidators(new IntegerRangeValidator());
```

**problem is** when data in ListGrid is filtred using

```
listPanel.setCriteria(criteria);
```

we get such exeption

```
12:42:31.204:RDQ2:WARN:Log:TypeError: _5 is null
ListGrid._clearingInactiveEditorHTML() @ adminApp/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:1530
GridBody.redraw(_1=>false) @ adminApp/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:889
[c]Canvas.clearRedrawQueue() @ adminApp/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:3300
[c]Class.fireCallback(_1=>{Obj},  _2=>undef,  _3=>[object Array],  _4=>{Obj}, _5=>true)
@ adminApp/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:299
Timer._fireTimeout("$ir2251") @ adminApp/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:1269
unnamed() @ adminApp/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:1264
unnamed() @
```

I've found similar question [here](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=9160) and [here](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=13298) but no solution was proposed.

**Are there any workarounds ?** *Thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set ListGridField to ListGrid

```
 listPanel.setFields(manualScoreColumn);
```

Another way to set editor of your choice to ListGridField is to use setEditorType method

```
    ListGrid listPanel = new ListGrid();
    listPanel.setCanEdit(true);
    listPanel.setAutoSaveEdits(false);

    //You can use any formitem instead of date item,Say TextItem,SelectItem etc
    DateItem dateItem = new DateItem();
    ListGridField dateListGridField= new ListGridField("date", "Date");
    dateListGridField.setEditorType(dateItem);
    listPanel.setFields(dateListGridField);
```